# UIButton array to add 3 buttons per row

Tags: ios, objective-c, for-loop, uibutton

I have a `UIButton` array with 6 buttons. What I want to do is add those buttons over my view in 3  chunks -- meaning 3 buttons in each row.

For that I am using two for loops. One for creating instance of all 6 buttons and the other for identifying the buttons count greater than 3.

But I am facing difficulty in adding `UIButton`s, one below the other. Here is my code for loop:

```
for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
{
    questButton=[UIButton new];
    for (int j=1; j<4; j++)
    {
        [questButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 30, 30)];
        [questButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Q%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [questButton setTag:i];

        [self.questionBtnArray addObject:questButton];

        questButton.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4f];
        [questButton release];
        x=x+40;
    }

    NSLog(@" button frame for %d button is :- %@",i,NSStringFromCGRect(questButton.frame));
    y=y+40;
}
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not ios or xcode person, but your logic here seems wrong. you say you have to place 6 buttons in two rows of 3 buttons each. but your loop is producing nearly 6 rows that too incorrectly. you don't have to use nested loops to achieve this. one if within will suffice. and note that certain values like x has to be re-initialized after you place three buttons and move to next row with increment in y.

try this :

```
for(int i=1;i<=6;i++)
            {
                questButton=[UIButton new];
                [questButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 30, 30)];
                [questButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Q%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                [questButton setTag:i];

                [self.questionBtnArray addObject:questButton];

                questButton.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4f];
                [questButton release];
                x=x+40;

                if(i==3) // three buttons placed, move to next row at starting column
                {
                    x=0; // or whatever initial value you have
                    y=y+40;
                }

            }
```

Comment: your welcome :), remember, you can use (i%3==0) instead of i==3 in case your no. of buttons increase and you still want them to be displayed in rows of 3 and 3

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
            {
                for (int j=1; j<4; j++)
                {
                    UIButton *questButton=[UIButton new]
                    [questButton setFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 30, 30)];
                    [questButton setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Q%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                    [questButton setTag:i];

                    [self.questionBtnArray addObject:questButton];

                    questButton.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.4f];
                    [questButton release];
                    x=x+40;
NSLog(@" button frame for %d button is :- %@",i,NSStringFromCGRect(questButton.frame));
                }

                y=y+40;
                x=0;
            }
```

Comment: Hi Dheeraj, thanks, but by using your code
its making 1 button in each row 3 times.

Comment: what is that extra ; in the for loop? I am curious to know about it. What does it do?

Comment: Hi Dheeraj, whats wrong in code below
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]init];
    int x = 10;
    int y = 20;
    for(int i=1;i<6;i++)
    {
        for (int j=1; j<4; j++)
        {
            button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,35, 35)];
            button.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"B%d",i] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            [button setTag:i];
            x = x+40;
            [self.myButtons addObject:button];
        }
        y=y+40;
        x=10;
    }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order elements in a matrix (here it's an `UIView`), I use to do this:

```
int maxElements = 6;         // Number of elements
int maxElementsPerRow = 3;   // You want only three elements per row
int xMarge = 40;             // x space between elements
int yMarge = 40;             // y space between elements
int elementWidth = 30;       // Size of element
int elementHeight = 30; 
CGPoint topLeftPos = CGPointMake(100, 100); // Top left position of first element

int elementCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0 ; i < maxElements ; i++)
{
    int row = (int)(elementCounter / maxElementsPerRow);
    int column = (int)(elementCounter % maxElementsPerRow);
    elementCounter++;

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake((xMarge + elementWidth) * column + topLeftPos.x, 
                              (yMarge + elementHeight) * row + topLeftPos.y,
                              elementWidth,
                              elementHeight);
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 

    // Do what you want with your element
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:v];
}
```